# How to deal with the log of a sum of more than two super small probabilities

Tags: r, probability, logarithm, underflow

For some evil reason I need to calculate the log of the sum of 500 super small probabilities, each term computed by

```
dmvnorm(X[,i], mean=rep(0,3), sigma=diag(3))
```

Sometimes the codes above return 0 due to underflow, but using logarithms will be fine.

```
dmvnorm(X[,i], mean=rep(0,3), sigma=diag(3), log=TRUE)
```

I know I can handle two terms mathematically: `log(p1 + p2) = log(p2) + log(1 + p1/p2)`. But Can we generalize this approach to more terms? Anyone with more experience on this?

---

BTW, I wrote a recursive function to compute this. Mathematically, it works. But I don't think this is practical.

```
MESSY <- function (pv) 
{
  N <- length(pv)
  if (N==1)
    {return(pv[1])}
  else
    {w <- pv[N]
     pv <- pv[1:N-1]-w
     return(w + log(1 + exp(MESSY(pv))))
    }
}
```

Because some p are super small and I can only use `w=log(p)`, we have `log(exp(w1)+exp(w2)) = w2 + log(1+exp(w1-w2))` and `log(exp(w1)+exp(w2)+exp(w3)) = w3 + log(1 + exp(w1-w3) + exp(w2-w3))` for two and three terms.

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example.  Also, if it is three terms, what would be the formula

Comment: Is `log(p2) + log(1 + p1/p2)` actually more accurate than `log(p1 + p2)`? Still seems like `p1/p2` would be problematic.

Comment: What is the goal of this?

Comment: This might help: https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2016/06/11/log-sum-of-exponentials/

Comment: Thanks! @akrun I just edited the post.

Comment: @Gregor--reinstateMonica-- You're right. It could be problematic. But some of the probability terms are too small, so I have to do it some other ways.

Comment: @KentJohnson Thanks a lot! That might be the most elegant solution! I can't find the function `log_sum_exp( )` or `logSumExp( )`, though. Do you know which package they're from?

Comment: I think they're in C source code underlying R, but not exported ... https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/nmath/pgamma.c#L219-L230 . Translating to R,  `logspace_add <- function(logx,logy) {
    max(logx,logy) + log1p(exp(-abs(logx - logy)))
}` (this is for two elements, would have to think about how to generalize it ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Yeah, that makes sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: @akash87 It's for the computation of Minimum-Description-Length scores, if that's what you're asking?

Answer (score 2):

This function is translated from the internal `logspace_add` function in the R source code [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/nmath/pgamma.c#L219-L230)

```
logspace_add <- function(logx,logy) { 
    pmax(logx,logy) + log1p(exp(-abs(logx - logy))) 
}
```

Not necessarily the most efficient, but you should be able to do this for >2 elements by using `Reduce()`:

```
logspace_add_mult <- function(x) {
    Reduce(logspace_add, x)
}
```

Quick test (using values that are large enough **not** to underflow, so that we can compare the results of the regular and logspace calculations).

```
x <- c(1e-4,1e-5,1e-6)
logspace_add_mult(log(x))
## [1] -9.10598
log(sum(x))
## [1] -9.10598
```

As far as I know, this is more or less the standard approach to logspace addition. The advantage of using something other than this home-grown implementation would be (1) code maturity and testing and (2) speed (at least for the `logspace_add_mult` version; I doubt there would be much advantage of a native-C (or whatever) implementation of `logspace_add`).  The [Brobdingnag package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Brobdingnag/index.html) uses similar representations:

```
library(Brobdingnag)
brob(log(x))
## [1] +exp(-9.2103) +exp(-11.513) +exp(-13.816)
sum(brob(log(x)))
## [1] +exp(-9.106)
log(as.numeric(sum(brob(log(x)))))
## [1] -9.10598
```

In Python, numpy has [logaddexp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.logaddexp.html), but this only works pairwise: you can use `functools.reduce()` to generalize it as above.

```
import numpy as np
import functools as f
x = np.array([1e-4,1e-5,1e-6])
f.reduce(np.logaddexp,np.log(x))
```

This is probably a little faster than `Reduce()` in R.

Comment: Thank you very much! This approach works, and it's so much faster. Although I got some unexpected results, so I suspect that underflow still happens for some terms only I don't get to see that. But I'm not sure. Would you recommend MATLAB or Python for such calculation?

Comment: I doubt there would be very much difference in the numerical stability.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To add to @BenBolker's answer A method to semi-vectorize `logspace_add`:

```
logspace_sum1 <- function(logx) {
  while (length(logx) > 1L) {
    if (length(logx)%%2) {
      m <- matrix(logx[-1], ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
      logx <- c(logx[1], pmax(m[,1], m[,2]) + log1p(exp(-abs(m[,1] - m[,2]))))
    } else {
      m <- matrix(logx, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
      logx <- pmax(m[,1], m[,2]) + log1p(exp(-abs(m[,1] - m[,2])))
    }
  }
  
  logx
}
```

Another option is to subtract off the maximum value in the vector before the `log(sum(exp()))` and then add it back on:

```
logspace_sum2 <- function(logx) {
  m <- max(logx)
  if (m < log(.Machine$double.xmin)) {
    log(sum(exp(logx - m))) + m
  } else log(sum(exp(logx)))
}
```

Testing and timing our options:

```
library(Rmpfr)
library(Brobdingnag)

funs <- c("log(sum(exp(logx)))",
          "Reduce(logspace_add, logx)",
          "logspace_sum1(logx)",
          "logspace_sum2(logx)",
          "as.numeric(log(sum(exp(as.brob(logx)))))",
          "as.numeric(log(sum(exp(mpfr(logx, 128)))))"
)
```

This first vector will underflow with a naive `log(sum(exp()))`.

```
set.seed(1688732183)

logx <- Rfast::dmvnorm(matrix(runif(3e4, 35, 40), 1e4, 3), numeric(3), diag(3), TRUE)
summary(logx)
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>   -2386   -2179   -2114   -2115   -2049   -1854
```

Create a matrix to hold the results.

```
logsumx <- matrix(0, length(funs), 1, dimnames = list(funs, NULL))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  list = setNames(lapply(lapply(1:length(funs), \(f) parse(text = sprintf("logsumx[%d] <- %s", f, funs[f]))), \(x) bquote({..(x)}, splice = TRUE)), funs),
  times = 1
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                                        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>                         log(sum(exp(logx)))     43.6     43.6     43.6     43.6     43.6     43.6     1
#>                  Reduce(logspace_add, logx) 595706.3 595706.3 595706.3 595706.3 595706.3 595706.3     1
#>                         logspace_sum1(logx)  11520.6  11520.6  11520.6  11520.6  11520.6  11520.6     1
#>                         logspace_sum2(logx)    336.6    336.6    336.6    336.6    336.6    336.6     1
#>    as.numeric(log(sum(exp(as.brob(logx)))))   7686.2   7686.2   7686.2   7686.2   7686.2   7686.2     1
#>  as.numeric(log(sum(exp(mpfr(logx, 128)))))  85986.4  85986.4  85986.4  85986.4  85986.4  85986.4     1

print(logsumx, digits = 22)
#>                                                                [,1]
#> log(sum(exp(logx)))                                            -Inf
#> Reduce(logspace_add, logx)                 -1854.051500721230695490
#> logspace_sum1(logx)                        -1854.051500721230922863
#> logspace_sum2(logx)                        -1854.051500721230922863
#> as.numeric(log(sum(exp(as.brob(logx)))))   -1854.051500721230922863
#> as.numeric(log(sum(exp(mpfr(logx, 128))))) -1854.051500721230922863
```

This second dataset will not underflow:

```
logx <- Rfast::dmvnorm(matrix(runif(3e4, 20, 25), 1e4, 3), numeric(3), diag(3), TRUE)
summary(logx)
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>  -932.4  -804.2  -763.4  -764.8  -725.0  -608.9

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  list = setNames(lapply(lapply(1:length(funs), \(f) parse(text = sprintf("logsumx[%d] <- %s", f, funs[f]))), \(x) bquote({..(x)}, splice = TRUE)), funs),
  times = 1
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                                        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>                         log(sum(exp(logx)))    624.7    624.7    624.7    624.7    624.7    624.7     1
#>                  Reduce(logspace_add, logx) 569796.5 569796.5 569796.5 569796.5 569796.5 569796.5     1
#>                         logspace_sum1(logx)   1733.6   1733.6   1733.6   1733.6   1733.6   1733.6     1
#>                         logspace_sum2(logx)   4033.4   4033.4   4033.4   4033.4   4033.4   4033.4     1
#>    as.numeric(log(sum(exp(as.brob(logx)))))   2880.3   2880.3   2880.3   2880.3   2880.3   2880.3     1
#>  as.numeric(log(sum(exp(mpfr(logx, 128)))))  76368.4  76368.4  76368.4  76368.4  76368.4  76368.4     1

print(logsumx, digits = 22)
#>                                                                [,1]
#> log(sum(exp(logx)))                        -608.3293532409613817435
#> Reduce(logspace_add, logx)                 -608.3293532409614954304
#> logspace_sum1(logx)                        -608.3293532409612680567
#> logspace_sum2(logx)                        -608.3293532409613817435
#> as.numeric(log(sum(exp(as.brob(logx)))))   -608.3293532409613817435
#> as.numeric(log(sum(exp(mpfr(logx, 128))))) -608.3293532409613817435
```

Of the methods that don't underflow, `logspace_sum2` has the best overall performance.